# Xml Deserialization - XmlElement wildcard in ElementName

Tags: .net, xml, wildcard, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an external xml into an object. I have no control whatsoever on this xml.

Here's an example:

```
<response>
 <date>2012-05-23 00:00:00</date>
 <users>
  <userObject0>
   <name>John</name>
   <surname>Smith</surname>
  </userObject0>
  <userObject1>
   <name>Jane</name>
   <surname>Doe</surname>
  </userObject1>
 </users>
</response>
```

I have no idea why it is done this way, and I cannot figure out how I can deserialize that xml to get an array of userObject.

Is it even possible?

**EDIT: Note that the project I'm working is in .net 2.0**

Answer (score 1):

If the data doesn't "fit" `XmlSerializer`, then: don't use `XmlSerializer`. Use an xml processor such as `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`, for example:

```
    var response = XElement.Parse(xml);
    var users = (from user in response.Element("users").Elements()
                 select new User {
                     Name = (string) user.Element("name"),
                     Surname = (string) user.Element("surname")
                 }).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I can't use this approach since I'm working with .net 2. Apologies for not making this clear. +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlSerializer to deserialize:

```
    // Remove numbers from userObject tags
    var xmlStringReplaced = Regex.Replace(xmlString, "<(/?)userObject[0-9]+>", "<$1userObject>");
    // XmlDeserialize the new XML string to a Response object
    var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlStringReplaced);
    var xmlSerialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response), new XmlRootAttribute("response"));
    var response = (Response)xmlSerialize.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

And the types to deserialize to:

```
public class Response
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("date")]
    public String DateXmlTemp
    {
        get { return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }
        set { Date = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }

    [XmlArray("users")]
    [XmlArrayItem("userObject")]
    public List<UserObject> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserObject
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("surname")]
    public String Surname { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use the number in the userObject tags you could change the Regex.Replace to add it as an attribute to the tag instead and then add a property to the UserObject class with and XmlAttribute("id") attribute.